# What is a sequence $a_n$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ exists, and also $\lim_{n \to \infty}[a_n/2^n] = 2$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

As title says: What is a sequence $a_n$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ exists, and also $\lim_{n \to \infty}[a_n/2^n] = 2$?

I've tried guess and check but got nowhere.

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: user-- I edited your question to go with Martin's suggestion. Let me know if needs anything more.

Comment: If $a_n\to a\in \Bbb{R}$ then $\frac{a_n}{2^n}\to 0$, so there is no such sequence.

Comment: Hint: If $\{a_n\}$ converges, then it's bounded.